# Range in Dojo's TimeTextBox

Tags: dojo

How can I limit the range shown in dojo's TimeTextBox?

According to the documentation [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/form/TimeTextBox.html) it should be possible via the min/max constraints but I have not found a way to apply them correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass dates to the max and min constraints

```
var today = new Date();

var today_9am = new Date(
    today.getYear(),
    today.getMonth(),
    today.getDay(),
    9, 0, 0);

var today_10am = new Date(
    today.getYear(),
    today.getMonth(),
    today.getDay(),
    10, 0, 0);    

var w = new dijit.form.TimeTextBox({
    value: today_9am,
    constraints: {
        min: today_9am,
        max: today_10am,
        timePattern: 'HH:mm:ss',
        clickableIncrement: 'T00:15:00',
        visibleIncrement: 'T00:15:00',
        visibleRange: 'T01:00:00'
    }
});
```

The widget won't accept dates outside the range. I just don't know how to make it so that it also doesn't show the invalid dates in the picker interface.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/missingno/skyWB/